# bootstrap 4 collapse not working smoothy in half its stopping then opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

This collapse is stopping in half then collapse completely...

I am collapsing 5 div in one collapse is this the reason ?? because in W3 schools it works fine... Should I change collapse to a panel...

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_collapse.asp

I used this one and in this, it working fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".logo-area").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("new-p");
    });
});
```

```css
#collapseOne {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 7%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    z-index: 200;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

#collapseOne div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3%;
}

#collapseOne p {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: black;
}

#collapseOne span {
    color: black;
}

#collapseOne hr {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: black;
}

.new-p {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo-area" id="fixedButton" for="collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse"
     href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
    <input type="image" src="images/creabaco-log2.png">
    <p class="logo-p">crebaco</p>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseOne">
    <div>
        <a href="index.html">
        <p>Crebaco.</p>
        <span>Overview.</span>
        <hr>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="test.html">
        <p>Services.</p>
        <span>What we do.</span>
        <hr>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="about.html">
        <p>About.</p>
        <span>Who we are.</span>
        <hr>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B'coz of you give `padding-top: 7%;` or `padding-bottom: 5%;`  into `#collapseOne`.

That's the reason on your smoothly effect. So please remove this css.

If are your trying to give space between your content then please add this css in your child id like:

`#collapseOne div{padding: 4% 0;}`

Hope this help.

Let me know further clarification.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".logo-area").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("new-p");
    });
});
```

```css
 #collapseOne {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 200;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

#collapseOne div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3%;
    padding: 4% 0;
}

#collapseOne p {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: black;
}

#collapseOne span {
    color: black;
}

#collapseOne hr {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: black;
}

.new-p {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo-area" id="fixedButton" for="collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse"
     href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
    <input type="image" src="images/creabaco-log2.png">
    <p class="logo-p">crebaco</p>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseOne">
    <div>
        <a href="index.html">
        <p>Crebaco.</p>
        <span>Overview.</span>
        <hr>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="test.html">
        <p>Services.</p>
        <span>What we do.</span>
        <hr>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="about.html">
        <p>About.</p>
        <span>Who we are.</span>
        <hr>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of giving padding to #collapseOne id, give padding to its child classes. This is what creating a jerk in your animation. Try giving padding to inner classes.